# Modular homework problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that:
$$[6]_{21}X=[15]_{21}$$

I'm stuck on this problem and I have no clue how to solve it at all.

Comment: What is making you stuck? Also, are you asked to find an $X$ that solves it?

Comment: solving it is not the same as showing it. if you where asked to show it it would mean it is  true for all x or a given set of numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Well, we know that $\gcd\ (6,21)=3$ which divides $15$. So there will be solutions:
$$
\begin{align}
6x &\equiv 15 \pmod {21} \\
2x &\equiv 5 \pmod 7
\end{align}
$$

because that $2\times 4\equiv 1 \pmod 7$, thus:
$$
\begin{align}
x &\equiv 4\times 5 \pmod 7\\
 &\equiv 6 \pmod 7
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree with giving a full solution to a homework question where the OP has not clarified where he is stuck.

Comment: I too downvoted for the same reason as Tobias.

Comment: Well, I'm upvoting to partially balance those two downvotes. Certainly a full solution for a homework question is not advisable, yet the solver is a brand new participant and I feel like we veterans should be more lenient and not to rush to downvote. A simple, well intentioned comment to the poster can equally do the job .

Comment: @DonAntonio I see what you mean. However, as there is no consensus to this (as can be seen from the number of upvotes), I would not feel right in writing a comment along the lines of "please don't do this". Herpderp: Please don't take this as discouraging you to answer questions in general, just homework questions where the OP has not had time to clarify the precise problem.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful, but ya sure, got it!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ 21\mid 6x\!-\!15 = 6x\!+\!6\!-\!21 \iff 21\mid 6(x\!+\!1)\iff 7\mid 2(x\!+\!1)\iff 7\mid x\!+\!1$

Answer (score 3):

One way is just to try all the choices for $X$, the integers from $0$ to $20$.  That isn't very many.

Another is to look for representatives in the class of $15$, which are numbers of the form $15+21k$, for one that is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: You write "look for *one*...", but there is more than one solution mod $21$.